# Matlab Serial Port: ErrorFcn Callback is not executed after Timeout

Tags: matlab, serial-port

i'm trying to do some serial communication with matlab. 
Settings are:
9600 baude
8 databits
0 paritybit
1 stopbit

main .m-file

```
SYN = 1;
FIN = 2;
ACK = 4;
NAK = 8;
PWM = 16;
MAG = 32;

txByte = 0;
rxByte = 0;

serobj = serial('COM3');
set(serobj,'Baudrate', 9600);
set(serobj,'Parity', 'none');
set(serobj,'Databits', 8);
set(serobj,'StopBits', 1);
set(serobj,'FlowControl', 'none');
set(serobj,'ErrorFcn',@TimeOutErrorFcn);
set(serobj,'Timeout',1);


fopen(serobj);

% Start the handshake
fwrite(serobj, SYN, 'uint8');
% wait for answer
rxByte = fread(serobj,1,'uint8');
if(isempty(rxByte))
    rxByte = 255;
end
% what is the answer?
switch (rxByte(1))
    case ACK+SYN
        fwrite(serobj, ACK, 'uint8');
    case NAK
        fclose(serobj);
    otherwise 
        fwrite(serobj, NAK, 'uint8');
        fclose(serobj);
end

while(strcmp(get(serobj, 'Status'),'open'))
% Do some communication
end
```

callback function as .m-file

```
function TimeOutErrorFcn(obj, event)
%TIMEOUTERRORFCN Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    disp('Error');
% close the connection here, send FIN and do fclose(serobj)
end
```

After the timeout is exceeded, the TimeOutErrorFcn is not called! All i get is the following output on the command promt:

```
Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.
```

Mathsworks help says:
Timeout

Waiting time to complete a read or write operation

You configure Timeout to be the maximum time (in seconds) to wait to complete a read or write operation.

If a time-out occurs, the read or write operation aborts. Additionally, if a time-out occurs during an asynchronous read or write operation, then:

```
An error event is generated.

The callback function specified for ErrorFcn is executed.
```

ErrorFcn

Specify the callback function to execute when an error event occurs
expand all in page
Description

You configure ErrorFcn to execute a callback function when an error event occurs.

```
Note    An error event is generated only for asynchronous read and write operations.
```

An error event is generated when a time-out occurs. A time-out occurs if a read or write operation does not successfully complete within the time specified by the Timeout property. An error event is not generated for configuration errors such as setting an invalid property value.

If the RecordStatus property value is on, and an error event occurs, the record file records this information:

```
The event type as Error

The error message

The time the event occurred using the format day-month-year hour:minute:second:millisecond
```

To learn how to create a callback function, see Creating and Executing Callback Functions.

So, I really don't see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing an asynchronous read operation, so therefore an error event doesn't occur.  Instead, it is a warning.  To force your error function to run, you need to tell Matlab to label that warning as an error.  Try adding this to the top of your code:

> warning('error', 'instrument:fread:unsuccessfulRead');

If there are other warnings that you want to flag as errors, you can get the command by issuing "verbose on".